# Request to Google Places API on iOS Returning REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: ios, exception, google-places-api, api-key, google-account

I'm not sure why I'm getting REQUEST_DENIED error when I'm using iOS key. When I used the one for web application, it works fine, but it's only for testing since I must test from specific IP address.

I followed the instruction on this page, [Obtaining an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#obtaining_an_api_key), but I still can't get it work. Do you know if there is something else I have to do? I made sure the bundle name is correct already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it seems like as of 09/09/13, there is no support for Places API for iOS. You have to use the one for web with any referrer rather than specify any static IP. Hope this help saves someone sometime. It took me quite a few hours to find this out.